# how to apply LIMIT/OFFSET on large table in sqlalchemy while getting intermediate result as well [please read the details below]?

Tags: python, mysql, sorting, sqlalchemy, filtering

I want to do 3 operations on a table which contains large number of records: (1)`filter` (based on a search query) (2)`order_by` (on a single column in asc/desc) and (3)`slice` (for given `offset` and `limit` values).

While carrying out these operations I need the intermediate result (obtained after filtering/sorting), to find out the number of records which satisfied the given filter query (to send this information to the front-end).

Right now I am using `FILTER` and `ORDER_BY` of sqlalchemy to get the intermediate result and then applying slicing on the list. How can I achieve the same using sqlalchemy's `FILTER`, `ORDER_BY` and `SLICE` together along with getting the number of records after filtering/sorting as a sub-result?

The sqlalchemy query I am using right now is as follows:

```
result = session.\
         query(Customer).\
         filter(Customer.name.like('%' + filter_query + '%') | Customer.email.like('%' + filter_query + '%') | Customer.partner.like('%' + filter_query + '%')).\
         order_by(asc(getattr(Customer, sorting_column_name))).\
         all()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
result = session.\
     query(Customer).\
     filter(Customer.name.like('%' + filter_query + '%') | Customer.email.like('%' + filter_query + '%') | Customer.partner.like('%' + filter_query + '%')).\
     order_by(asc(getattr(Customer, sorting_column_name))).\
     slice(offset,limit).\
     all()
```